# Using sed on a single column

Tags: shell, command-line, sed

Here is a command I'm running 
It takes anything of the form (a number)(b or q) //a number followed by a b or a q
And replaces it with either b or q

```
cat Table1.txt | sed -r 's/[0-9]([bq])/\1/g'

ex. 8q -(changes to)> q
    7b -(changes to)> b
```

But I wan't this to be done only on the second column so

```
tyek8qk 9b88 column
uel76qk 8q76 word
```

Would change to

```
tyek8qk b88 column
uel76qk q76 word
```

This is my attempt so far but it just produces exactly what is input

```
cat Table1.txt | sed -r '2,2s/[0-9]([bq])/\1/g'
```

Comment: Shouldn't `9b88` be changing to `b88` as per first `sed` command?

Comment: @anubhava Yes it would but the first one would also change tyek8qk to tyekk

Comment: At some point you're going to have to take a shell programming class or read a book on the subject. This trial and error stuff you seem to be doing is the wrong way to learn shell programming. I recommend Shell Scripting Recipes by Chris Johnson and Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: description and output sample don't match.  You say it should replace with b or q but in the output it doesn't.  Which is correct?

Comment: @EdMorton Already took one! It was a second year university course!

Comment: I hope it doesn't come across as being rude but you need to take another one as your questions are absolutely basic and the things you are trying to do in your attempts are things that should never be done (e.g. google UUOC). Maybe read those books I mentioned?

Comment: @EdMorton That will come I just assigned a very difficult task this summer that I was unprepared for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this sed:

```
sed -E 's/([^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+)[0-9]([bq])/\1\2/' file

tyek8qk b88 column
uel76qk q76 word
```

If you have gnu awk then can do this:

```
awk '{$2=gensub(/[0-9]+([bq])/, "\\1", 1, $2)} 1' file
```

Comment: Thank-you, is that the only way to do it though? I just don't really understand what the [[:blank:]]+ are doing and how you determine how many you need to determine what what column will be worked on

Comment: It also just makes my commands more difficult, there isn't some sort of thing like the 2,2 that would work

Comment: `sed` doesn't work on column basis. `([^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+)` matches first column and whitespace after that. I will provide a gnu-awk alternative also.

Comment: so if I wanted to do something like ([^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+) but with the third or fourth column how would I do that?

Comment: I suggest using `awk` for handling data based on column and rows.

Answer (score 1):

Another option in awk is to use substr.

```
awk '{$2=substr($2, 2, 3)}1' file
tyek8qk b88 column
uel76qk q76 word
```